# Searching by vote type (not by score)

Tags: feature-request, search, voting, statistics, data-dump

I understand some people read this question as if I'm discussing the merits of down-voting.

This isn't the case.

My question is - how could I collect empirical data regarding the use of downvotes, so I can observe its effects?

And because the answers I found indicate that it might be impossible to collect this empirical data, I am requesting that the feature be added - so we add a `downvoted:true` or `downvoted:1...` search option.

This could allow users to detect poor answers that could be improved or learned from, as well as perhaps controversial  (i.e. `user:mine is:a downvotes:5... upvotes:5...`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the data explorer, for example [this query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1346876).

```sql
select top 1000 
  postid as [Post Link]
, sum(case when votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) [upvotes]
, sum(case when votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) [downvotes]
, sum(case when votetypeid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) - sum(case when votetypeid = 3 then 1 else 0 end) [score]
, count(*) [total]
from votes v
group by postid
order by downvotes desc 
       , score
```

Votes are still anonymous, also in SEDE so you can't search for your own votes, let alone the votes of others. But for empirical data collection that doesn't seem needed anyway.

For more info on the database schema see: [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede)

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know this existed and it definitely helps! ... I still think the data would be more accessible by adding `downvotes` and `upvotes` to the normal search engine (especially as I have no idea how you knew about the vote type values), but it solves my immediate need and shows that the data is accessible :)